# AWS Wix App Runner error: DB Config Status Missing props jwtPublicKey, appDefld

Tags: amazon-rds, velo, aws-app-runner

I followed the Wix database integration with AWS tutorial to relatively the same steps in order to get myself adjusted with this integration aspect of a project I'm working on. This is the tutorial that I followed and I set up an Aurora MySQL database: https://dev.wix.com/docs/develop-websites/articles/databases/external-databases/aws/integrate-your-aws-databases-with-your-wix-site.

As the title explains, I keep getting this error in regards to missing props. After some research it looks like there are some aspects missing from my environment variables, but not sure exactly how to adjust for that in my settings.

**EDIT:**
I tried to upload an image of what I am getting as an error, however when trying to upload an image to StackOverflow I am getting an error for "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" which, according to the Meta page is a DNS error. In short, on the App Runner host website, my DB Config Status is red with the specified error in the title, Permissions is yellow (as I haven't specified a group), and Connection Status is green.